# How to get counts from multiple Models eloquent [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I know how to get records count for a model :

```
User::count();
```

But how can I get counts from multiple models in one eloquent query?

Comment: please explain more what you want, set all your models you want to get count from them

Comment: You said multipe models, set us an example

Comment: Yes I need count on multiple models with single query

Comment: Why do you have to get multiple counts in one query? This doesn't make sense. What do you want to get from the query? Please attach an example.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Do you want to get total records of all models?